# How do I create and send an email to a specific address in Java?

Tags: java, email

How do I create and send an email using Java? I am using NetBeans 8.2 as my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at apache commons-email library, it has all features to work with emails out-of-the-box.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/

Comment: Thanks so much. I’ll definitely check it out.